# What does this statement do when executed?

Tags: java, vector, double

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class DoubleVectorQuestion
{
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {
        Vector<Double> thisVector = new Vector<Double>();
    }
}
```

So i was recently asked this question on a quiz and i did not get the answer correct.  The question was exactly

"What does the following statement do?" (Code above)

The four choices were along these lines. (Dont know exactly what they were but this is similar)

> - It creates an empty vector to create a vector of Double objects.
> - It creates a vector with 10 elements to create a vector of Double objects.
> - This statement does not do anything.
> - It creates an array of Double objects.

Comment: What did you answer and why?

Comment: It creates an empty `Vector` intended to hold `Double` values.

Comment: I answered that it does nothing. (It was early in the morning and I wasn't thinking)  I saw later that it does something even though it doesn't display it but I do not understand what it does.

Comment: This is pretty fundamental, so if you don't understand it, you should read your books again.

Answer (score 2):

It definitely does something...

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

> `Vector()`
>
> Constructs an empty vector so that its internal data array has size 10 and its standard capacity increment is zero

Now, your answer could be "creates an array", but I'm guessing you weren't being quizzed on the underlying data, so "creates an empty vector" would be more correct. However, you may want to consult with `thisVector.size()` on that.

Answer (score 1):

The first choise is the correct. It creates the object in heap but then do nothing (terminates)

Comment: "Creates an empty vector" is more correct than "does nothing", though.

Comment: i mean nothing more than that ;)